# WEBPAGE loads wrong after form_validation set_Rules codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

It is possible after set_rules in form_validation, something like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('empfact', 'Nome da Empresa','trim|required|xss_clean');
```

This action modify my webpage layout? it is this possible in any case?

Because i am with a problem and the problems occurs after this action (set_rules).

The problem is: after i submit a form and set_rules, my webpage load with a white space in top of the page with +/- 10px of height.

Plus: in IE (only in IE) after perform this action, my webpage load without some images and align left.

Any ideas?

form controller

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|matches[emailconf]|callback_value_email|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('emailconf', 'Confirmação de Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwd', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[passconf]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('empfact', 'Nome da Empresa', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contr', 'Nº Contribuinte', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'Nome', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('apelido', 'Apelido', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('morada', 'Morada', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('codpostal', 'Código Postal', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('localidade', 'Localidade', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('telefone', 'Telefone', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('telemovel', 'Telemóvel', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('myform');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}

public function value_email($str)
{
    $this->load->model('carfinder_model');

    // Validate exists
    $result = $this->carfinder_model->confirmExistence('email', $str);

    // Now we verify the result
    if(! $result)
    {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('value_email', 'O e-mail escolhido já está registado');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

myForm view

```
<!-- content -->
<section id="content">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="indent-bot-12">
        <h2 class="indent-bot-2">Registe-se agora no CarFinder-PRO.pt</h2>
        <ul class="list-box">
            <li>
                <h3 class="indent-bot-7">Para utilizar os serviços CarFinder-PRO.pt, é necessário registar-se. O registo permite-lhe aceder à listagem dos veículos, reservá-los e encomendá-los. O registo é rápido e gratuito.</h3>
                <p class="indent-bot-15">*O registo é exclusivo a comerciantes profissionais. Após o registo a sua conta só será ativada depois de passar o processo de validação. Todos os campos são de preenchimento obrigatório.</p>
            </li>
            <?php if(validation_errors())
            {
                echo '<li>';
                    echo '<div class="val-errors">';
                            echo '<div class="val-image">';
                                echo '<img src="../../images/stopp.png" alt="" />';
                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '<div class="val-text">';
                                echo validation_errors();
                            echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</li>';
            }?>
            <li>
                <?php echo form_open('form'); ?>
                <p class="indent-bot-15">*Dados de Acesso</p>


                    <b><label for="email"><?php if(form_error('email')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Email</label></b>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(! form_error('email')) { echo set_value('email'); } ?>" size="40" />
                    <br />

                    <b><label for="emailconf"><?php if(form_error('email')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Confirmar Email</label></b>
                    <input type="text" name="emailconf" value="<?php if(! form_error('email')) { echo set_value('emailconf'); } ?>" size="40" />
                    <br />
                    <!-- <h5>Username</h5>
                    <php echo form_error('username'); ?>
                    <input type="password" name="username" value="<php echo set_value('username'); ?>" onfocus='this.value="";' onblur='if (this.value=="") this.value = "E-mail:";' size="50" /> -->

                    <b><label for="passwd"><?php if(form_error('passwd')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Password</label></b>
                    <input type="password" name="passwd" value autocomplete="off" size="25" />
                    <br />

                    <b><label for="passconf"><?php if(form_error('passwd')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Confirmar Password</label></b>
                    <input type="password" name="passconf" value autocomplete="off" size="25" />
                    <br />
            </li>
            <li>
            <p class="indent-bot-15">*Dados Pessoais</p>
                    <b><label for="empfact"><?php if(form_error('empfact')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Nome da Empresa</label></b>
                    <input type="text" name="empfact" value="<?php if(! form_error('empfact')) { echo set_value('empfact'); } ?>" size="40" />
                    <br />

                    <b><label for="contr"><?php if(form_error('contr')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Nº Contribuinte</label></b>
                    <input type="text" name="contr" value="<?php if(! form_error('contr')) { echo set_value('contr'); } ?>" size="25" />
                    <br />

                    <b><label for="nome"><?php if(form_error('nome')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Nome</label></b>
                    <input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php if(! form_error('nome')) { echo set_value('nome'); } ?>" size="40" />
                    <br />

                    <b><label for="apelido"><?php if(form_error('apelido')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Apelido</label></b>
                    <input type="text" name="apelido" value="<?php if(! form_error('apelido')) { echo set_value('apelido'); } ?>" size="40" />
                    <br />

                    <b><label for="morada"><?php if(form_error('morada')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Morada</label></b>
                    <input type="text" name="morada" value="<?php if(! form_error('morada')) { echo set_value('morada'); } ?>" size="40" />
                    <br />

                    <b><label for="codpostal"><?php if(form_error('codpostal')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Código Postal</label></b>
                    <input type="text" name="codpostal" value="<?php if(! form_error('codpostal')) { echo set_value('codpostal'); } ?>" size="40" />
                    <br />

                    <b><label for="localidade"><?php if(form_error('localidade')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Localidade</label></b>
                    <input type="text" name="localidade" value="<?php if(! form_error('localidade')) { echo set_value('localidade'); } ?>" size="40" />
                    <br />

                    <b><label for="telefone"><?php if(form_error('telefone')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Telefone</label></b>
                    <input type="text" name="telefone" value="<?php if(! form_error('telefone')) { echo set_value('telefone'); } ?>" size="25" />
                    <br />

                    <b><label for="telemovel"><?php if(form_error('telemovel')) { echo '<div class="imgset"><img src="../../images/markerred.jpg" alt="" /></div>'; } ?> Telemóvel</label></b>
                    <input type="text" name="telemovel" value="<?php if(! form_error('telemovel')) { echo set_value('telemovel'); } ?>" size="25" />
                    <br />

                <br /><br />*Ao clicar no botão Registar, declara que aceita as <a href="#">Condições Gerais de Utilização</a> da CarFinder bem como os seus <a href="#">Termos e Condições</a>.
                <br /><br />
                <div><input class="button-registo" type="submit" value="Registar" /></div>
                <br />
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you actually run form validation before displaying the page again? If yes, does the validation fail or not? In any case, are you not loading other view after validation? And finally, have you tried checking with Firebug what's causing the 10px gap?

Comment: Yes i run form_validation before. If i reload the form view is because form_validation fails. i load header view form view and footer view

Comment: I can't understand with firebug what is causing the 10px gap, but is strange because firebug says the <title> is inside the <body> :O

Comment: Can you show more code please?

Comment: Firebug shows a white line without anything after <body> but i don't know what is this line

Comment: i added code, if you consider anything more relevant tell me and i add

Comment: Before the submit everything is ok in firebug, title is inside the head etc, after the submit everything changes

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the problem.
Was a very stupid problem, but maybe this POST can be useful to other programmers in the future.

I selected in NOTEPAD++ to do the text codification in UTF-8 (Standard is ANSI) <- this was the problem.

Now everything is working fine,

Ty all.

Comment: I thought it was going to be an issue, but only today saw your code. Well done in sorting this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can left an empty 'div' to hold the error in views like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php echo form_error('empfact','<div class="error">','</div>'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my problem or i didn't explain it well. I don't have any problem in showing the form errors in my view. My problem is regarding the way form_validation and set_rules affect my layout.

Comment: For instance in my form the input fields have height: 20px; after submit the form and reload again the form view the height of inputs change to default value.

Comment: I think just the 'error' that display nearby input affect the page.So you can pre-specify the style in error place.

Comment: Even when i don't show the errors in my page the layout change when i do set_rules in my controller

Comment: It is very strange, After i submit the form if i don't set rules, everything is ok, no bugs, but in the other hand if i set rules in form_Validation, the webpage layout goes wrong EVEN when i don't display any errors in the screen even when i comment the validation_errors(); line code

Comment: In the form do you have set the form_open() function? If not, check if the submit method is post. And you can also use firebug to find out what make it to be strange.

Comment: ? ? ? As you can check in my code above i have form_open() function, and i am trying to find the problem with firebug but i am not being capable of

Comment: Your codes goes well in my environment, and notice that I have had comment the lines://$this->load->view('header');
//$this->load->view('footer');

Comment: Yes like i said, i also don't have any problem here if i comment this two lines

Comment: This problem is always after the setting of the rules.
Right now I did a new experiment:
In my main page I load: header myform and footer, when I submit form
in my form controller index function I only load header and footer views and I face the same problem in top of the page

Comment: So, the problem isn't related with myform view.

Comment: OK, you would be delighted to have worked out the problem. Charset must be the first thing to be solved.:)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going to find the answer/problem is in your CSS.

You are also loading two different views based on whether or not the form(myform) is validated. So you aren't actually reloading on form submit, you are loading a NEW view (formsuccess), and probably introducing different element nesting, CSS, etc.

Debug your page by loading only one view (myform). Turn off the conditional statement for now, and worry about myform. Form validation in CodeIgniter can be accomplished with one view. That's why the User Manual suggests those inline `php` function calls, which I see in your markup. Try getting that page to work. Then worry about dumping to a 'success' page.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I already tried to take off all the CSS's and the problem persists.
Is a really strange problem. 
If i only load myForm view i can't detect any problem, because my problem is in top of the page and with input fields that change height (but of course they don't if i didn't use the css and didn't put them different)

Comment: This is being a really strange problem, and the biggest problem is that i don't know where i should search to solve it.
I already tried to load just only 1 view, tried to erase all the CSS, tried to load myForm view without any of form_error() functions.
The only case when i don't have any problems is when i comment all set_rules in form controller

Comment: Furthermore, I don't have any problems when form_validation is TRUE. So you can forget that part of formsuccess.

Comment: Your last comment seems to be the answer...If form_validation==true, no errors are shown, and formSuccess is shown. So it is most likely that either your CSS for `if(form_error('email')) { echo '<div class="imgset">...` is causing a problem (specifically `.imgset`, or you possibly are wrapping your _error `<div>`s inside of additional `<p>` tags from CodeIgniter's error function.